# how to loop image up and down using JS?

Tags: javascript, image, jquery-animate

I'm a beginner in JS and need some help! I have a div with 270px height, and a 365px height image inside it. What I need is the image to loop up and down, so people can see it all...

This is my html:

```
<div class="destaquetodo">
    <div class="destaqueconteudo">
        <div class="destaquecapa">
             <img src="/imagens/2013/se-beber-nao-case-3/grande"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="destaquebox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: api.jquery.com/animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!

You dont need any JS to do this, with a little bit of CSS3 [Animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) and [Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) you can achieve a great effect, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9nvB/1/

```
@keyframes up-down-loop {
    0% {
        top: 0;
    }
    50% {
        top: -95px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

With this `@keyframe` you have a great effect, just adapt it to your project :)

Comment: thanks, it worked pretty good, ill use it... but theres any way to keep the position it is when you move the mouse out of it?

thanks again!

Comment: without js i dont think so

Comment: edit: actually you can do it with only CSS YAAYY!!! Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/k9nvB/1/